# .Net Core Ajax form submit not returning non binded model property

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have .Net core web project with form ajax submit. While loading the form, I am setting all property value to the view model. But while posting, it returns only property that binded to the html input. The other values are coming null. How can I get all the view model properties I passed to the form.

**Controller**

```
    public IActionResult General(string templateId)
    {
        return View(new TemplateGeneralViewModel { Id = "12-3", Name = "Name", Code = "code" });

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult General(TemplateGeneralViewModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Cshtml**

```
<form asp-area="AdminPanel" asp-controller="Template" asp-action="General"
      method="post" data-ajax-begin="OnFormAjaxBegin" data-ajax-complete="OnFormAjaxComplete"
      data-ajax-failure="OnFormAjaxFailed" data-ajax-success="OnFormAjaxSuccess"
      data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST">
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tf1">Id</label>
        <input type="email" asp-for="Id" class="form-control" id="tf1" aria-describedby="tf1Help" placeholder="e.g. johndoe@looper.com">
        <small id="tf1Help" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="tfValid">Name</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control is-valid" id="tfValid">
        <div class="valid-feedback"> Success! You've done it. </div>
    </div>
   
</form>
```

**View Model**

```
public class TemplateGeneralViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }


}
```

Here the property 'Code' is null on submit. How can I get this value without using any hidden field ?

Comment: Also add .cshtml file code

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the model returned in the Post action is not the same instance of the model returned in the Get action. Is built anew with the data present in the html. Where is the field for the code property in your cshtml? Nowhere so when the model is created anew to pass it back in the post action no value could be given.

Just add the field and if you don't want to show it, add the style to hide it

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="tfValid">Name</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control is-valid" id="tfValid">
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Success! You've done it. </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" asp-for="code" class="d-none">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the other data in query string with `asp-route-{value}`,you can refer to the official doc of [anchor tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0).Here is a piece of sample code which passes Id,Name and Code to action:

```
<form asp-area="AdminPanel" asp-controller="Template" asp-action="General"
      method="post" data-ajax-begin="OnFormAjaxBegin" data-ajax-complete="OnFormAjaxComplete"
      data-ajax-failure="OnFormAjaxFailed" data-ajax-success="OnFormAjaxSuccess"
      data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" asp-route-Code="@Model.Code">
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tf1">Id</label>
        <input type="email" asp-for="Id" class="form-control" id="tf1" aria-describedby="tf1Help" placeholder="e.g. johndoe@looper.com">
        <small id="tf1Help" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="tfValid">Name</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control is-valid" id="tfValid">
        <div class="valid-feedback"> Success! You've done it. </div>
    </div>
   
</form>
```